# IMG on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have some images on my web, which grow on hover.
On mobile devices they grow on click. But once I click them and they grow I can't shrink them back by clicking again. So I can't see other images. This is only on mobile, since on bigger screens it's on hover, not click. Don't really know how to fix this issue.

```css
.container-interests {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  line-height: 0;
}

.box>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 10vh);
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box>span {
  font-size: 3.8vh;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vh;
  line-height: 2.6;
}

.box:hover {
  flex: 0.5 0.5 35%;
}

.box:hover>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .box:hover {
    flex: 0.5 0.5 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-interests">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="assets/css/img/trekking.jpg">
    <span><i class="fas fa-mountain"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="assets/css/img/mountain.jpg">
    <span><i class="fas fa-hiking"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="assets/css/img/camping.jpg">
    <span><i class="fas fa-campground"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="assets/css/img/argentina.jpg">
    <span><i class="fas fa-plane"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="assets/css/img/biking.jpg">
    <span><i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="assets/css/img/pets.jpg">
    <span><i class="fas fa-dog"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hover on mobile touchscreen devices doesn't work the way you think. But i think what you expect can be achieve using this method. Please Read it https://medium.com/@mezoistvan/finally-a-css-only-solution-to-hover-on-touchscreens-c498af39c31c

Comment: you could try some javascript `onClick` event handlers

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. The thing is, `hover` works differently on mobile devices than on PC versions. Because mobile devices don't have a property like mousemove.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) 
 {
        .box:hover { flex: unset; }
 }
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick answer. I just tried it, but it didn't work. Still zooming in the photo on mobile, and once zoomed in I cannot see or click any other image. What I want to do is to be able to click it again and zoom it out, to be able to select another photo.

Comment: As soon as I am free, I will solve this problem for you. Please wait a little.

Comment: Let's clarify again. On mobile screens, you want your pictures to enlarge on click, and on the second click, shrink back to their original size. So?